# jquery mobile and phonegap free application requires a licence?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, licensing

as i am new in android platform i was coding with jquery mobile ui and phonegap/cordova. Submitting an application that includes jquery mobile and phonegap/cordova requires any licence process? The application is free/non commercial (not for selling/commercial)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope! Both are Open Source and their licenses allow for you to submit applications to Google's Play Store